# Where is the recursive call?

Tags: scala, recursion, shapeless

I have following product type implementation in shapeless:

```
trait CsvEncoder[A] {
  def encode(value: A): List[String]
}

implicit val hnilEncoder: CsvEncoder[HNil] =
createEncoder(_ => Nil)


implicit def hlistEncoder[H, T <: HList](
                                        implicit
                                        hEncoder: CsvEncoder[H],
                                        tEncoder: CsvEncoder[T]
                                      ): CsvEncoder[H :: T] =
createEncoder {
  case h :: t =>
    hEncoder.encode(h) ++ tEncoder.encode(t)
}
```

and it is used as follow:

```
val reprEncoder: CsvEncoder[String :: Int :: Boolean :: HNil] =
  implicitly
println(reprEncoder.encode("abc" :: 123 :: true :: HNil))
```

Looking at the instance implementation of `HList`, I can not see the recursive call anywhere. Because `HList` is like a list, it should process recursively but I can not configure it out where that happened.

Answer (score 3):

It happened in `tEncoder.encode(t)`. In particular let's analyze the following code:

```
case h :: t =>
  hEncoder.encode(h) ++ tEncoder.encode(t)
```

`case h :: t` deconstructs the `HList` in its head and tail parts. Then `hEncoder.encode(h)` converts the value `h` of type `H` into a `List[String]`. Afterwards `tEncoder.encode(t)` recursively encode the remaining `HList` until it reaches the *base case* represented by `HNil` for which the result is `Nil`, that is the empty `List`. The intermediate results are concatenated using `++` which is the operator used to concatenate two Scala `List` instances.